# Can Aggregate Root Factory create the root, and it's internal classes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, dsl, aggregateroot

Currently, my aggregates and value objects have protected constructors and almost all of them are being created by static factory methods inside the aggregate with descriptive names. It creates a nice **DSL** and pretty encapsulated model **but makes the unit testing painful** (if the domain model creation fails, the service/command handler will be marked as failed as well). Introducing factory methods on the other hand for each entity, and value object forces me to inject a factory interface per entity/value object into the service.

Is it ok to create a factory service per aggregate root with a factory method per entity/value object? 
Here's an example of a factory service which creates a company aggregate root, and it's internal entities/VOs:

```
public class CompanyFactory : ICompanyAggregateRootFactory
{
    public Company CreateCompany(...){}
    public Employee CreateEmployee(...){}
    public CEO CreateCEO(...){}
    ....

}
```

Is there any other way which enforces the same level of encapsulation and **DSL** clarity without making the unit tests depending on one another?

Answer (score 0):

The blue book has a chapter about factories. And yes it is totally ok to create a factory for your aggregate root. The internal implementation of this factory doesn't matter a lot. You can use other factories for value objects or any other way. 
I have one suggestion: I don't know a lot about your domain but I thing the employee should be a separate aggregate. And CEO is actually an employee so maybe you should rethink this design.